# Bootstrap 5 in Angular Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Since version 5 **Bootstrap** framework has removed **jQuery** as a requirement.

**I want to know how this change affects the Angular application?**

Can we use all provided Bootstrap functionalities in Angular (for example dropdowns)?

I know that Angular shouldn't be combined with JQuery - in earlier versions of Bootstrap, JQuery was recommened to import if we want to use all bootstrap functionalities and it was bad.

But Bootstrap 5 doesn't rely on JQuery anymore so is it safe to use it with my Angular applications?

As for now I don't want to use bootstrap alternatives like ng-bootstrap, that is why I'm asking is it okay and **safe** to use Bootstrap 5 in Angular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use it now. You can use it by installing with npm as well as by including the CDN links in your project.

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You can also check the implementation of the bootstrap 5 in angular 11 here. - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/add-bootstrap-5-in-angular-11/

Comment: ng-bootstrap was a way to implement Bootstrap without JQuery dependency. So now, Bootstrap removed JQuery. Does it mean that ng-bootstrap don't have sense now?

Comment: Actually, the `ng-bootstrap` was designed to work without jquery so that users can use it without jquery. But now bootstrap is available without jquery itself. So it completely depends upon you, which approach you choose for yourself.

Comment: @LovekeshKumar, a suggest you install the bootstrap and change the angular.json file

Answer (score 43):

to install bootstrap simply use

```
npm install bootstrap
```

And edit the angular.json file

```
        "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", //<--add this line
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" //<--and this line
        ]
```

Comment: This worked! IMPORTANT: you have to restart the compiler (ng serve) so the changes in angular.js can work.

Comment: note that using `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` you dont need to install poppers, but if you use `bootstrap.min.js` you should do.

Comment: for everbody wondering why there is no "popper" js here. It is included in the bundle. So you do not need to add popper to your dev dependencies and you do not have to add the popper .js under scripts here.

Answer (score 5):

step 1: `npm install bootstrap --save`

step 2: Open `src/style.css`

Add the following line of code to the style.css

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

Answer (score 4):

## You first need to install the Node Package Manager

You then install Bootstrap in your project using your IDE's Terminal. In Visual Studio code this can be brought up by clicking CTRL + ` or going to the View Menu.

You then install Bootstrap 5 in your project with the following command.

`npm install bootstrap@next`

You then have to import that package so that Angular is aware of it. You do this by adding the necessary directives in the Angular.json file.

[image: angular.json file]

You then add the following path to the CSS.

`"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",`

And the following to the JS

`"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"`

### You can then also add the popper JS.

Using the following NPM command you can add popper.js to your project.

`npm install @popperjs/core`

Then also adding the directive to your angular.json file

`"./node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js"`

So that your angular.json file looks like this.

[image: Angular.json complete]

Answer (score 0):

To install `bootstrap` in `angular` application use below command in `terminal`

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

Now open `angular.json` file and add below line in `styles` section

```
 "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
```

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

```
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

Bootstrap says you need to

> use a framework-specific package instead of the Bootstrap JavaScript

Reference: [Bootstrap - Usage with JavaScript frameworks](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/javascript/#usage-with-javascript-frameworks)