# Angular cannot access bootstrap from node_modules when I provide path in angular.json file

Tags: css, angular, typescript, npm, angular-bootstrap

I am trying to install bootstrap in my Angular project.

1. I used `npm install --save bootstrap` to install bootstrap in my project
2. After that I installed jquery
3. Provided path for bootstrap

Below is the angular.json file:

```
"styles": [
          "../node_modules/boostrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
```

When I pass the above bootstrap path in style.css it works but I want to make it work by passing the path to angular.json.

style.css file`@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"`

All the paths that I tried are mentioned below:

"./node_modules/boostrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"

"node_modules/boostrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"

"../node_modules/boostrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"

Comment: See that the bootstrap 5 needn't jquery, see [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68081166/bootstrap-5-in-angular-application/68082635#68082635)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my proyect I have it like this.

```
"./node_modules/boostrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
```

But keep in mind that if you don't stop the serve and run again `ng serve`, it will not show the change as the import is made at the begining of the ng serve process.

hope it works for you.

If you changed the angular.json from the location of the original configuration, let me know wo we can figure it out the correct path

Comment: It worked by re-running using ng-serve.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. after i update styles.css file with following code it worked.

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

then i remove that and used following code in angular.json

```
       "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
        ]
```

Then i re run `ng serve` as told here. It worked. thanks