# Bootstrap burger menu not worked

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-5

I copied the navbar from the bootstrap navbar documentation, but when I click, the hamburger menu does not work for me, it just does not display the nav items for me.
[my hamburger menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1R6G.png)

My code in bs-navbar.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <img src="../../assets/images/logo.png" alt="" width="55" height="60"/>
    <a class="navbar-brand fw-bold ms-4" href="#">medochek</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Замовити</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Контакти</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Галерея</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Про мед</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <span class="navbar-text">
        +380 66-842-45-32
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I use Angular so I'm imported bootstrap like this: `@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"` in styles.css

Comment: Did you import the required js files as well? You have to write the js code to dynamically add and remove CSS class functionality from the menu element to show/hide on the click of the hamburger button or you have to utilise the mentioned js files to add the required functionality.

Comment: @RohitKhandelwal I didn't import any js files

Comment: Added the imports for reference in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the following imports in your framework's import style to be imported for the bootstrap navbar button to work and also for all the styles visible completely.

> ```
>   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
>   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
>   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
> ```

The compatible versions of the above links you can check & replace for the bootstrap version you are using.

The second option is you can write your own `javascript` code to `add/remove` dynamic `CSS` active class from your navbar menu.

Comment: I import this links in head of index.html and it isn't work.

Comment: The above links are for bootstrap 3 and for reference only. Are you using the same? You should check & replace the versions which will match your bootstrap version.

Comment: @Marko Dont use script tags. Instead do it like this in angular.json: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68082635/4394435

Comment: you do not need jquery for bootstrap 5 either. and you don't have to include popper js script when you use the bundled version.