# Bootstrap is not working in Angular 16. I tried to set the script and style but still it didn't work

Tags: angular, angular16

Bootstrap is not working.

[Here is the script and style detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQZNS.png):

```
"styles": [ 
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", 
    "src/styles.scss" 
    ],
"scripts": [ 
     "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
     "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
     "node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js"
     ]
```

[Here is the code I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdlfQ.png) but it didn't work:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Page 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Page 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Page 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here is the result I am getting is below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7WNL.png)

Comment: "styles": [  
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",              
              "src/styles.scss"              
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
            "node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js"

The above code i already tried.but no result

Comment: Please share your code as snippet instead of images. Meanwhile, which Bootstrap version you used? v4 or v5?

Comment: I am not able to edit the question and comment not allow me to post the code as its long

Comment: Even after i have added script and style bootstrap is not working for me.
"styles": [  
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",              
              "src/styles.scss"              
            ],
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
            "node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js"
            
            ]

Comment: <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using? The code for your nav-var it's not  looks like the examples (looks like your forget add the `class="nav-item"` to the li tags). BTW, if you use Bootstrap 5, the only script you need is `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` **or** `popper.min.js` and `bootstrap.min.js` (rememeber in this last case that Popper must come first)

Comment: The vesion is Bootstrap  v5.3.0 ,
and the code i tried is 
 "styles": [  
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",              
              "src/styles.scss"              
            ],
            "scripts": [
             "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
             "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            
            ] 

Still not working

Comment: Check this bro:https://youtu.be/TIGy3VYsG5g

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68081166/bootstrap-5-in-angular-application/68082635#68082635

Comment: Have you restarted your angular app after adding these styles? When you make a change in angular.json you need to stop and start the app again

Comment: (1) Please delete all code in the comments above, and add it to the question (if you have not already done so); (2) please clarify all four instances of the phrase "not working" in your question. It doesn't offer a lot of detail about what is not going as expected for you. Could you be more specific? What did you expect?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to styles.css:
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";