# How to use bootstrap dropdowns?

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I have to make a dropdown like this in the picture:

[image]
[image]

I tried using code from this url: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/ , but it won't work.I did install bootstrap.

> "bootstrap": "^5.3.1",

html code:

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
  

  <div class="btn-group">
  <button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle"
    data-toggle="dropdown"
    aria-haspopup="true"
    aria-expanded="false"
  >
    Action
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what I get:

[image]

How should I write my typescript code? Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you installed version 4 of Bootstrap? The most recent version is 5.3. Make sure the docs you're looking at match the installed version. Also make sure you're including both the CSS and JS files. Also, for dropdowns make sure you have also installed the "popper" dependency.

Comment: Like @Lewis already said - You need popper.js and make sure you installed bootstrap correctly. The code doesn't differ from version 4 to 5. I assume you didn't install bootstrap accordingly.

Comment: @SickerDude43 The code does differ ever so slightly between the two. While the classes are largely the same, the events are slightly different - i.e, `data-bs-toggle` for 5 vs `data-toggle` for 4 etc. But you're right, that probably doesn't account for the lack of styling.

Comment: to install bootstrap 5, see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68081166/bootstrap-5-in-angular-application/68082635#68082635). in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fob4q5?file=src%2Fmain.ts) I made an angular app with a dropdown, select acordeon and nav. See that the code it's the same that the [examples of bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/dropdowns/)

Answer (score 0):

your bootstrap version is "bootstrap": "^5.3.1",
soo you can get the dropdown from here [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/dropdowns/#overview)